# Typesetting chord progressions

Tags: tables, music

For this to work, you need to install the [New Real Book fonts](http://web.archive.org/web/20130630050923/http://notation.jochenpietsch.de/nrbkchrd.zip) and the experimental [`realbookchords` package](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/realbookchords) by cgnieder, then compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

I'm working on a simple set of macros to typeset chord progressions. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, collcell, realbookchords}
\setlength{\unitlength}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\|}{\rule[-.2\unitlength]{.7pt}{1.4\unitlength}} % measure bar
\newcommand{\zif}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{l}{\fbox{\sffamily #1}}\\} % ziffer
\newcommand{\hd}{\Large\textsf{\o}} % half diminished
\newenvironment{chordprog}[1]
               {\bigskip\bigskip
                \SongTitle{#1}
                \par\medskip\noindent
                \begin{tabular}{l !{\|} l !{\|} l !{\|} l}}
               {\end{tabular}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\collectcell\rbc}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newenvironment{chordprog*}[1]
               {\bigskip\bigskip
                \SongTitle{#1}
                \par\medskip\noindent
                \begin{tabular}{ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ}}
               {\end{tabular}}
\setmainfont{Century Gothic}
\RBCsetup{songtitle-format-center={\rmfamily\LARGE\bfseries}}

\begin{document}
\begin{chordprog}{After You've Gone}
\zif A
\rbc{Abmaj} & \rbc{Abmi6} \rbc{Db9} & \rbc{Ebmaj} & \rbc{Gmi7} \rbc{C9} \\
\rbc{F9}   & \rbc{Bb9} & \rbc{Eb6} & \rbc{Bbmi7} \rbc{Eb7} \\
\zif B
\rbc{Abmaj} & \rbc{Abmi6} \rbc{Db9} & \rbc{Ebmaj} & \rbc{Gmi7} \rbc{C9} \\
\rbc{Fmi} \rbc{C7alt} & \rbc{Fmi7} \rbc{Db9} & \rbc{Ebmaj} \rbc{D\hd} \rbc{G7} & \rbc{Cmi7} \rbc{A0} \\
\rbc{Eb6} \rbc{C7} & \rbc{Fmi7} \rbc{Bb7} & \rbc{Eb6} & \rbc{Bbmi7} \rbc{Eb7}
\end{chordprog}

\begin{chordprog*}{At Last}
\zif{Intro}
F && F7 && Bb && B0 && F & F7/{Eb} & D7\b9 && Db7 && C7\\
\zif{Verse 1.}
F && Dmi7 && Gmi7 && C7 && F && Dmi7 && Gmi7 && Cmi7  & C7 \\
F && Dmi7 && Gmi7 && C7 && F & F7/{Eb} & D7\b9 && Db7 && Gmi7 & C9 \\
\end{chordprog*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Comments:** In the unstarred environment, one tabular cell corresponds to one measure; in the starred version, one cell is one quarter note. The latter is needed when I want to align the beats, and not only the measures. It also allows me to wrap the table cell in the `\rbc` (realbookchord) macro, but creates more space even when there are one or two chords in a measure.

I'm asking for

1. How to simplify / beautify this code? (The vertical bar seems hackish.)
2. How to make the starred environment as narrowly spaced as the unstarred one? May not be as beautiful, but I want to print it out on small paper and stick it onto a synth with no music stand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing between the tabular columns. Below I use

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\collectcell\rbc}l<{\endcollectcell}@{\,}}
```

The `\@{\,}` suppresses the usual inter-column space and adds `\,` instead.
In the tabular column specification I suppressed in the beginning completely:

```
\tabular{@{}ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ}
```

I also made small changes to the environment definitions. The `\begin` and `\end` are not needed. They add an additional group and will lead to misleading error messages if there is some erroneous input.  The changes also reflect a small fix I made to the `\SontTitle` command. The new version of `realbookchords` can be found [on the Bitbucket site](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/realbookchords/overview).

Since I prefer to see every quarter in these kinds of leadsheet I added a version with a small rule for every quarter with no chord change. (It's not a perfect solution, though). I'd also add measure bars at the beginning and the end of each line, too.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,collcell,graphicx}
\usepackage{realbookchords}[2013/09/07]
\setlength{\unitlength}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\|}{\rule[-.2\unitlength]{.7pt}{1.4\unitlength}} % measure bar
\newcommand{\zif}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\fbox{\sffamily #1}}\\[3pt]} % ziffer
\newcommand{\hd}{\Large\textsf{\o}} % half diminished

\protected\def\qu{\rotatebox{-45}{\rule[.75ex]{2pt}{8pt}}}

\newenvironment{chordprog}[1]
  {%
    \par
    \SongTitle{#1}%
    \par\medskip\noindent
    \tabular{@{}l !{\|} l !{\|} l !{\|} l}%
  }
  {\endtabular\bigskip\bigskip}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\collectcell\rbc}l<{\endcollectcell}@{\,}}
\newenvironment{chordprog*}[1]
  {%
    \par
    \SongTitle{#1}%
    \par\medskip\noindent
    \tabular{@{}ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ !{\|} ZZZZ}%
  }
  {\endtabular\bigskip\bigskip}
% \setmainfont{Century Gothic}
\RBCsetup{songtitle-format-center={\rmfamily\LARGE\bfseries}}

\begin{document}

\begin{chordprog}{After You've Gone}
\zif A
\rbc{Abmaj} & \rbc{Abmi6} \rbc{Db9} & \rbc{Ebmaj} & \rbc{Gmi7} \rbc{C9} \\
\rbc{F9}   & \rbc{Bb9} & \rbc{Eb6} & \rbc{Bbmi7} \rbc{Eb7} \\
\zif B
\rbc{Abmaj} & \rbc{Abmi6} \rbc{Db9} & \rbc{Ebmaj} & \rbc{Gmi7} \rbc{C9} \\
\rbc{Fmi} \rbc{C7alt} & \rbc{Fmi7} \rbc{Db9} & \rbc{Ebmaj} \rbc{D\hd} \rbc{G7} & \rbc{Cmi7} \rbc{A0} \\
\rbc{Eb6} \rbc{C7} & \rbc{Fmi7} \rbc{Bb7} & \rbc{Eb6} & \rbc{Bbmi7} \rbc{Eb7}
\end{chordprog}

\begin{chordprog*}{At Last}
\zif{Intro}
F && F7 && Bb && B0 && F & F7/{Eb} & D7\b9 && Db7 && C7\\
\zif{Verse 1.}
F && Dmi7 && Gmi7 && C7 && F && Dmi7 && Gmi7 && Cmi7  & C7 \\
F && Dmi7 && Gmi7 && C7 && F & F7/{Eb} & D7\b9 && Db7 && Gmi7 & C9 \\
\end{chordprog*}

\begin{chordprog*}{At Last}
 \zif{Intro}
  F   & \qu     & F7    & \qu &
  Bb  & \qu     & B0    & \qu &
  F   & F7/{Eb} & D7\b9 & \qu &
  Db7 & \qu     & C7    & \qu \\
 \zif{Verse 1.}
  F    & \qu & Dmi7 & \qu &
  Gmi7 & \qu & C7   & \qu &
  F    & \qu & Dmi7 & \qu &
  Gmi7 & \qu & Cmi7 & C7 \\
  F    & \qu & Dmi7 & \qu &
  Gmi7 & \qu & C7 & \qu &
  F & F7/{Eb} & D7\b9 & \qu &
  Db7 & \qu & Gmi7 & C9 \\
\end{chordprog*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for fixing the songtitle indentation. In the end I completely abandoned the originally unstarred environment and went for the second one, because it's easier to enter and with the suppressed space, looks almost the same.