# Should additional groups be avoided?

Tags: environments, grouping

Should **additional** groups like `\begin{algorithm} ... \end{algorithm}` be generally avoided and the use of `\algorithm...\endalgorithm` be preferred?

By additional is meant, that there is at least one other group. For clarification see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386951/defining-a-permanent-look/386959#386959) answer and it's comments.

### Some answers where it's told to do so:

> I also made small changes to the environment definitions. The \begin
>   and \end are not needed. They add an additional group and will lead to
>   misleading error messages if there is some erroneous input.

*from [Typesetting chord progressions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132025/typesetting-chord-progressions/132075#132075)*

---

> Secondly, rather than writing \begin{algorithm}...\end{algorithm}
>   inside your environment I would just use \algorithm...\endalgorithm.
>   The two are almost the same except that that the first version puts
>   everything inside its' own group, which isn't really necessary here
>   because your environment starts its own group.

*from [Multiple Counters on algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326566/multiple-counters-on-algorithm/326572#326572)*

---

I'm unsure if [When to use or avoid grouping?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95228/when-to-use-or-avoid-grouping) is related.

### Where it isn't done:

In [Group statements, avoid pagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149692/group-statements-avoid-pagebreak/149696#149696) the use of `\begin{xyz} ... \end{xyz}` is chosen.

Comment: Try: `\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\foolen}
\newenvironment{foo}{\setlength{\foolen}{17pt}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}

\end{foo}

\the\foolen

\foo
\endfoo
\the\foolen


\end{document}`. The grouping mechanism is established within the environment, so `\foo` and `\endfoo` are sufficient. Using `\foo` and `\endfoo` outside of the environment group there will be no group, unless `\foo` and `\endfoo` are explicitly defined this way, see the various examples in `latex.ltx`

Comment: The grouping is to be considered whether redefinitions of commands, lengths or count register values (for examples) should persist only in a group and not leak outside. LaTeX counters are group-safe, however, and there is no unique answer for this

Comment: I understand your comments. My question was a bit unclear, I updated it.

Comment: Ben: I understood your request about the 'additional' groups. There's no clear answer in my point of view. Verbatim-like wrapper environments however should see `\end...` instead of `\end{...}`, as far as I know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard latex syntax is `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` in some, but not all, cases this can be "optimised" to `\foo....\endfoo` but only if you know in detail how the environment is defined, and that the non standard call will work.

A few environments that use special handling have a *requirement* to use the `\foo`... `\endfoo` form if used inside a nested `\newenvironment` definition (eg `tabularx` and  `ams` alignments) but these are special constructs where the non-environment form is explictly documented  in the package documentation.

Comment: So the answer I gave (linked from the question) is OK? It isn't wrong?

Comment: @cfr no looks Ok to me (you could add an `\ignorespacesafterend` which was added to latex partly to remove one possible reason for preferring the `\endfoo` syntax over `\end{foo}`  but in most list uses that doesn't actually make a difference on practice.